# How to improve the performance of the query

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, nosql

```
r.db('DB').table('TB').group('message').map(function(doc){
  return {
    count: 1,
    from: doc('timestamp'),
    to: doc('timestamp'),
    browsers: r([doc('ua')('family')])
  }
}).reduce(function(left, right){
  return {
    count: left('count').add(right('count')),
    from: r.branch(left('from').lt(right('from')), left('from'), right('from')),
    to: r.branch(left('to').gt(right('to')), left('to'), right('to')),
    browsers: left('browsers').setUnion(right('browsers'))
  }
}).ungroup().orderBy(r.desc(r.row('reduction')('count'))).limit(100)
```

**What I want to do is to:**

1. group all the documents by `message`
2. find the earliest and latest timestamp from each group
3. find all the distinct tags in a group

I would like the result to be something like:

```
{
    'message': 'message content shared by the group',
    'earliest': 1431307840000,
    'latest': 1431307849999,
    'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
}
```

I need to perform this query quite frequently (to render the initial content of the webpage), so the performance is a concern. But the performance is very upsetting. With a table of 15k documents, this query executed for 4.5s. **Any idea on how to improve?**

The profile of the query is here:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Evaluating limit.",
    "duration(ms)": 4134.771499,
    "sub_tasks": [
      {
        "description": "Evaluating orderby.",
        "duration(ms)": 4134.327403,
        "sub_tasks": [
          {
            "description": "Evaluating ungroup.",
            "duration(ms)": 4113.544033,
            "sub_tasks": [
              {
                "description": "Evaluating reduce.",
                "duration(ms)": 4113.241578,
                "sub_tasks": [
                  {
                    "description": "Evaluating map.",
                    "duration(ms)": 0.082467,
                    "sub_tasks": [
                      {
                        "description": "Evaluating group.",
                        "duration(ms)": 0.073697,
                        "sub_tasks": [
                          {
                            "description": "Evaluating table.",
                            "duration(ms)": 0.028392,
                            "sub_tasks": [
                              {
                                "description": "Evaluating db.",
                                "duration(ms)": 0.015104,
                                "sub_tasks": [
                                  {
                                    "description": "Evaluating datum.",
                                    "duration(ms)": 0.001565,
                                    "sub_tasks": []
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "description": "Evaluating datum.",
                                "duration(ms)": 0.000356,
                                "sub_tasks": []
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "description": "Evaluating datum.",
                            "duration(ms)": 0.000331,
                            "sub_tasks": []
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "description": "Evaluating func.",
                        "duration(ms)": 0.00122,
                        "sub_tasks": []
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "description": "Evaluating func.",
                    "duration(ms)": 0.000805,
                    "sub_tasks": []
                  },
                  {
                    "description": "Perform read.",
                    "duration(ms)": 4112.207454,
                    "sub_tasks": [
                      {
                        "parallel_tasks": [
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 4044.006493,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 4043.993961,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 4078.153662,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 4078.142774,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 3972.17768,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 3972.167594,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 4024.771149,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 4024.760748,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 4036.958792,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 4036.948958,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 3995.32926,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 3995.318271,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 3916.118836,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 3916.106312,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            {
                              "description": "Perform read on shard.",
                              "duration(ms)": 3970.473735,
                              "sub_tasks": [
                                {
                                  "description": "Do range scan on primary index.",
                                  "duration(ms)": 3970.462526,
                                  "sub_tasks": []
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "description": "Evaluating desc.",
            "duration(ms)": 0.003855,
            "sub_tasks": [
              {
                "description": "Evaluating func.",
                "duration(ms)": 0.002151,
                "sub_tasks": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "description": "Sorting in-memory.",
            "mean_duration(ms)": 0.014517,
            "n_samples": 1245
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "description": "Evaluating datum.",
        "duration(ms)": 0.000359,
        "sub_tasks": []
      },
      {
        "description": "Evaluating stream eagerly.",
        "mean_duration(ms)": 0.000061,
        "n_samples": 101
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post how much team each part of the query takes to execute? What's the execution time if you take out the `reduce` part? The `map part? the `group` part? Also, is this a query you'll be running continuously? (Is there a reason it needs to be fast?)

Comment: Hi, @JorgeSilva . I made some updates towards your comment.